# Is it possible to return data to Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I want to be able to ask dialogflow a question and have it query a data source to return a response.

For example....

1) Ask what items are on my shopping list

2) Dialogflow queries a csv file (my shopping list)

3) Dialogflow recites/lists the items on the list

So the flow of data should be be [User -> Dialogflow -> Data source -> Dialogflow ->User]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - yes.

Dialogflow can send JSON to a [fulfillment webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) with the query information, and that fulfillment is expected send JSON back with the information. What you do as part of that fulfillment is pretty much up to you, as long as you can do it in just a few seconds.

So the flow would be:

User -> Dialogflow -> Fulfillment -> Dialogflow -> User

Comment: If you have specific questions about how to do this, check out the documentation on fulfillment, try it out, and post a new question with specific problems that you're having. StackOverflow works best with specific issues, rather than general questions.

Comment: ooooooo, so it looks like I need to add some code to my api specifically that returns the webhook response 

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_response

So I could ask my api a question, query a DB or something then return an entry or list of entries.